# Weakly convergent subsequence in a Hilbert space (Bass Exercise 19.7)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am asking about a problem in Bass's real analysis, which is as follows: Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space, and let $\{x_n\} \subset H$ be a sequence such that $\sup_n ||x_n|| \leq 1$. Prove that there is a subsequence $\{n_j\}$ and an element $x \in H$ with $||x|| \leq 1$ such that $x_n \to x$ weakly, i.e., $\langle x_n,y \rangle \to \langle x,y \rangle$ for all $y \in H$.

I have seen a couple of different ways to go about this, but I am attempting my own solution and having trouble justifying the last bit, so I am here to seek advice on whether this works or not. Here is my method: We can let $\{u_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$ (existence of an orthonormal basis is consequence of Zorn's Lemma). An orthonormal basis is complete, so for $x \in H$ we have the properties $||x||^2 = \sum_{\alpha \in A} |\langle x,u_\alpha \rangle|^2$ (Parseval's identity), and $x = \sum_{\alpha \in A} \langle x,u_\alpha \rangle u_\alpha$ where countably many $\langle x,u_\alpha \rangle$ are nonzero, and where this series is well-defined up to any re-ordering of the terms. Enumerate basis elements $\{u_{\alpha_\ell}\}_{\ell \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \{u_\alpha\}$ so that this sequence contains all $u_\alpha$ for which some $n$ has $\langle x_n,u_\alpha \rangle \neq 0$.

For all $n,\ell$, we have $|\langle x_n,u_{\alpha_\ell} \rangle|^2 \leq ||x||^2 \leq 1$, so for $\ell = 1$, let $\{1_j\} \subset \mathbb{N}$ be a subsequence such that $\langle x_{1_j},u_{\alpha_1} \rangle$ converges to a limit $\gamma_1$. Proceed to construct subsequences inductively: if $\{(k-1)_j\}$ is a subsequence such that $\langle x_{(k-1)_j},u_{\alpha_\ell} \rangle$ converges to a limit $\gamma_\ell$ for all $1 \leq \ell \leq k-1$, choose $\{k_j\}$ to be a subsequence of $\{(k-1)_j\}$ such that $\langle x_{k_j},u_{\alpha_k} \rangle$ converges to a limit $\gamma_k$. Finally, construct a subsequence $\{\beta_j\}$ such that $\beta_1 \in \{1_j\}$, and for all $k \geq 2$, $\beta_k > \beta_{k-1}$ such that $\beta_k \in \{k_j\}$. Then $\lim_{j \to \infty} \langle x_{\beta_j},u_{\alpha_\ell} \rangle = \gamma_\ell$ for all $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$. Now, consider $x = \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \gamma_\ell u_{\alpha_\ell}$. WTS that $||x|| \leq 1$, and $x_n$ weakly converges to $x$.

For all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $\sum_{\ell=1}^N |\gamma_\ell|^2 = \lim_{j \to \infty} \sum_{\ell=1}^N |\langle x_{\beta_j},u_{\alpha_\ell} \rangle|^2 \leq 1$, so $\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty |\gamma_\ell|^2 \leq 1$, and $x = \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \gamma_\ell u_{\alpha_\ell}$ is well-defined with $||x|| \leq 1$, right? I am not sure how to show $x_{\beta_j} \to x$ weakly, or if this is even true. To show $\langle x_n,y \rangle \to \langle x,y \rangle$ for $y \in H$, my thought is to write $y = \sum_{\alpha \in A} \langle y,u_\alpha \rangle u_\alpha$, and to show $|\langle x_{\beta_j},y \rangle - \langle x,y \rangle| = |\langle \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \langle x_{\beta_j},u_{\alpha_\ell} \rangle u_{\alpha_\ell},\sum_\alpha \langle y,u_\alpha \rangle u_\alpha \rangle - \langle \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \gamma_\ell u_{\alpha_\ell}, \sum_\alpha \langle y,u_\alpha \rangle u_\alpha \rangle| = |\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \langle x_{\beta_j},u_{\alpha_\ell} \rangle \langle u_{\alpha_\ell},y \rangle - \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \gamma_\ell \langle u_{\alpha_\ell},y \rangle| = |\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty (\langle x_{\beta_j},u_{\alpha_\ell} \rangle - \gamma_\ell) \langle u_{\alpha_\ell},y \rangle| \to 0$. Any thoughts on whether this will work, or conversely, if this method has a counterexample? I am very curious to know if this last step can be justified.

Comment: You need to use the dominated convergence theorem for your last step as you want to take the limit in the series.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! We need a dominating function $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $|g| \geq |\langle x_{\beta_j},u_{\alpha_\ell} \rangle \langle u_{\alpha_\ell},y \rangle|$ for all $j$, right? I am not sure how to identify such a $g$ that is integrable, i.e. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |g(n)| < \infty$. Or did I misunderstand what you mean?